# How to determine which part(s) do not support 4K @ 60 Hz (potentially HDR) via HDMI?

Tags: hdmi, tv, intel-graphics, asus-laptop, 4k-resolution

I’ve just bought a TCL 40P62US supposedly 4K HDR TV (I can check using its built-in YouTube app that 4K HDR @ 60fps works, although the HDR effect is so-so), however I can’t yet get 4K SDR @ 60fps over HDMI, much less 4K HDR, and I'm frustrated trying to make it work.

Will the picture pixelate or stutter when the HDMI cable cannot handle the bandwidth?

Because currently, 4K 60p does not show at all in my notebook’s resolution selection. The max I can select is 4K 30p. I have:

- [ASUS GL552VW](https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-GL552VW/) with a 1080p SDR display, no mention whether the HDMI port is 1.4, 2.0, 2.0a, or 2.0b (not in the manual, and no info on the net), but considering HDMI 2.0 was released 2 years before this notebook, I initially expect it to have at least HDMI 2.0, <del>especially because Intel HD 530 supports it</del> (see below).
- Intel HD 530, supports 4K @ 60p (not sure if it supports HDR there). However, this laptop also has [NVIDIA GTX 960M](https://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-960M.138006.0.html) which only supports HDMI 1.4. **Update:** From [NotebookCheck](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-530.148358.0.html): (see also my answer)

  > Displays can be connected via DP 1.2 / eDP 1.3 (max. 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz), whereas **HDMI is limited to the older version 1.4a (max. 3840 x 2160 @ 30 Hz)**. However, HDMI 2.0 can be added using a DisplayPort converter. Up to three displays can be controlled simultaneously.
- Windows 10 latest, supports 4K HDR @ 60p
- <del>Cliptec 3 m “high-speed” cable. I’ve lost the packaging, and this is definitely not premium certified. However, I’m suspecting that it is 10.2 Gbps instead of 18 Gbps. And at 3 m it’s also longer than "short distance" HDMI so I'm worried about that.</del> **Update:** I now use [Vention B05 18 Gbps](http://vention.org/detail/c:categories/p:01/n:6) 2 meters cable. So at least now I'm pretty sure the cable is not the issue.
- TCL 40P62US (Netflix-branded, it even has a Netflix button on the remote). This is probably the entry-level-est 4K “HDR” TV possible, a $315 one. The manual says nothing of the HDMI or even the panel’s specs. The panel is <del>the [RGBW pseudo-4K similar to entry-level LG 4K TVs](http://4k.com/lgs-2017-4k-rgbw-tvs-keep-offering-a-raw-deal-for-consumers-22793-2/)</del> similar to [P607's "crosshatching" panel](https://www.rtings.com/tv/reviews/tcl/p-series-2017-p607#comparison_1772) and [*some* S405 "crosshatching" panels](http://i.rtings.com/images/reviews/tv/tcl/s405/s405-user-1-large.jpg). The HDMI ports are only labeled HDMI and HDMI (ARC). Contrary to TCL's high-end models, I can't find any specs of this TV on the Internet either, including on TCL's website (this is TCL Indonesia's variant and TCL Indonesia does not even have a website).

  Based on what I see, it is similar to [P6US](https://www.amazon.in/TCL-139-7-inches-P6US-Smart/dp/B07B7MVWLB) sold in India and other countries. The OS is TV+ (not Android and not RokuOS).

I don’t care about HDR over HDMI “currently”, since I use this TV mainly for work instead of watching movies. But I do care about 4K (SDR) @ 60 fps. So I have 3 candidates that prevent me that: 1. The notebook, 2. the TV, <del>3. the cable</del>. Upgrading the notebook or the TV would be expensive, while the cable is cheapest, but I’d like to know first which part is the problem.

My issue is that I can’t select 4K @ 60 fps **AT ALL**, not that I can select it then it displays artifacts. In fact, I can’t select 60 fps for any 16:9 resolution above 1080p. So no 60 fps for 1600p either. Had I been able to select 4K @ 60 fps then noticed artifacts, I would’ve bought new cables already.

**Update:** Although 2560x1440 and 2848x1600 are not in the standard resolutions list, I managed to use these resolutions **at 60 Hz** via Intel's Custom Resolution.

My ultimate question is which part is "at fault"? Will buying new cables allow me to use 4K @ 60 fps? Or more specifically, does my current cable PREVENT selection of 4K @ 60 fps, instead of still allowing it with artifacts?

I want to buy a cable that claims HDMI 2.0b 18 Gps with 1.8 m length... However I won’t do that if it won’t change my current situation at all. If the real problem is with my TV or notebook or both, then I’d rather wait until it’s time to upgrade either of them (to support not just 4K 60fps but 4K HDR), and upgrade the cable also at that time (and get a 48 Gbps cable with 4K HDR support and beyond). But I want to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Intel HD 530, supports 4K @ 60p (not sure if it supports HDR there).

The `Intel HD 530` does not support HDR10.  The `Intel HD 530` only supports HDMI 1.4.  HDR10 requires at the minimum HDMI 2.0b.

Additionally, the `Intel HD 530` only supports 4K @60 Hz, if you are using DisplayPort.  This does not include converting a DisplayPort signal to HDMI.  The `Intel HD 530` would still be limited to the feature set of HDMI 1.4 in that case.

[image]

Source: [Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ Processor](https://ark.intel.com/products/88967/Intel-Core-i7-6700HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz)

> However, this laptop also has NVIDIA GTX 960M which only supports HDMI
>   1.4.

Indeed which means it has the same limitations as the `Intel HD Graphics 530` and would support the same resolutions.  The specifications on the Nvidia website, indicate, it does not have a DisplayPort connection.

> ASUS GL552VW, no mention whether the HDMI port is 1.4, 2.0, 2.0a, or 2.0b

It's HDMI 1.4 since the [Nvidia GPU](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-960m/specifications) and the [Intel GPU](https://ark.intel.com/products/88967/Intel-Core-i7-6700HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz) only support HDMI 1.4.

> GM107 integrates the sixth generation of the PureVideo HD video engine (VP6), offering a better decoding performance for H.264 and MPEG-2 videos. Of course, VP6 supports all features of previous generations (4K support, PIP, video encoding via NVENC API). Unfortunately, HDMI 2.0 is still not supported.

Source: [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M](https://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-960M.138006.0.html)

> TCL 40P62US. This is probably the entry-level-est 4K “HDR” TV possible, a $315 one.

While your television is slightly different, the only product line even close to the description you have provided is the Series 4 which is the lowest 4K display that TCL even manufactures.

The following table from TCL, based on the description you provided of your television, matches the Series 4 product line feature set.  Since you also believe your television has an S405 panel, and I believe it to be a Series 4, that has been modified for a specific region.  **You have a Series 4 TCL television.**  Which means the following table applies to your television.

[image]

Source: [TCL ROKU TV: 4-SERIES](https://www.tclusa.com/products/home-theater/4-series)

As for the reason it indicates "HDR" support, that most likely is handled by software, there are a couple IPS displays manufactured by LG that handle HDR support through software also.

> The panel is similar to P607's "crosshatching" panel and some S405 "crosshatching" panels.

You have an S405 panel.  **You do NOT have a P607 panel.**  While you do not have a panel from LG, the following description of what actually is happening with the Series 4 panels, still applies to your television.

> The HDR mode will automatically activate if the monitor receives a compatible signal, but the device only relies on a software-based implementation. When active, the HDR representation adds a nice touch of extra color pop and a seemingly deeper contrast range, although the monitor’s limitations will come into play here.

Source: [LG 27UK650](https://superuser.com/questions/1335393/does-displayport-1-2-support-hdr/1335410#1335410)

> My ultimate question is which part is "at fault"? Will buying new cables allow me to use 4K @ 60 fps?

**Your hardware does not support the resolutions you want while it's connected over an HDMI connection.**  It does not matter what revision the cable supports, your GPUs, do not support the resolutions at the refresh rate you want.

> How to determine which part(s) do not support 4K @ 60 Hz (potentially HDR) via HDMI?

**Your hardware does not support 4K@60 Hz HDR.**  Your television uses software to improve the picture quality, so while it might be advertised as an HDR panel, it actually isn't.  The `Intel HD 530` nor `NVIDIA GTX 960M` contained in your device can support 4k@60 Hz HDR since neither supports the appropriate DisplayPort or HDMI standard.

> currently, 4K 60p does not show at all in my notebook’s resolution selection.

It is not being displayed because it's not supported.

> Will the picture pixelate or stutter when the HDMI cable cannot handle the bandwidth?

The picture is pixelating and stuttering because the hardware does not support it.  While a better quality cable might reduce that effect, **you are attempting to do something**, your hardware does not support.

> I don’t care about HDR over HDMI “currently” since I use this TV mainly for work instead of watching movies. But I do care about 4K (SDR) @ 60 fps. So I have 3 candidates that prevent me that: 1. The notebook, 2. the TV, 3. the cable. Upgrading the notebook or the TV would be expensive, while the cable is the cheapest, but I’d like to know first which part is the problem.

Your laptop is the reason you cannot use 4K SDR @ 60 Hz.

> My ultimate question is which part is "at fault"?

Your television barely meets the requirements to be considered an HDR 4K television.  It actually doesn't even have actual HDR functionality.  Your laptop has a 1080p IPS panel, and neither GPU, support the resolutions you are asking about.

> I want to buy a cable that claims HDMI 2.0b 18 Gps with 1.8 m length

An HDMI 2.0b cable will not solve your problem.  Your hardware does not support what you want.  An HDMI 2.0 to DisplayPort converter will not help in this case.  Your hardware does not have a DisplayPort connection.

> So that means only some of my hardware can't support 4K@60 Hz (both
>   SDR and HDR).

**Your hardware does not support 4K HDR.**

Comment: I was talking about if the television had a DisplayPort and you downgraded the signal to HDMI 2.0

Comment: Oh you mean if the TV had DisplayPort, converting the HDMI 1.4 from the laptop to DisplayPort would not allow it to support anything beyond what HDMI 1.4 allows.   That makes sense, you might want to switch HDMI and DisplayPort around in the quoted text in that case.

Comment: I don’t really feel my statement needs clarification

Answer (score 1):

I tried Intel's Custom Resolution and I managed to get these resolutions to work at 60 Hz (so for you that are having similar problem as me, this is probably your best bet):

- 2560 x 1440 @ 60 Hz. Timing: CVT-RB. Scaling: 125%.
- 2848 x 1600 @ 60 Hz. Timing: CVT-RB. Scaling: 125% or 150%.

Any resolution above 2848x1600 with 60 Hz immediately gives me "the custom resolution exceeds the maximum bandwidth capacity" error.

With these resolutions with the Cliptec 3 m cable I sometimes get artifacts which looks like flickering horizontal thick line, probably twice a minute.

I replaced with a new [Vention B05 18 Gbps](http://vention.org/detail/c:categories/p:01/n:6) 2 meters cable, unfortunately it still doesn't allow me to use higher resolutions for 60 Hz refresh rate issue, but at least it seems to fix the artifacts.