# How to output 4K60 HDR to a capable TV?

Tags: hdmi, 4k-resolution, hdr

I have 2 TVs that have HDR capability, both display HDR videos with the built-in Youtube app perfectly.

I also have a 2.1 HDMI cable which in theory can transfer 8K or 4K120 without problem, but when I use that cable to connect 2 MacBook Pro's (one Intel and one ARM M2) to one of the above TVs I can only get 4K30 non-HDR output, no matter which settings I tried or which color profile I chose. The same thing applies when I use Linux on another laptop with the same cable and TV combination. But if I use Windows on that laptop I can use 4K60, although still no HDR

Why is that? How to fix that problem?

**Update:** I've also tried connecting the MBPs to a Dell U2718Q which apparently supports HDR, the connection is reported as HDMI 2.0 but still no HDR option available

Comment: What the GPU and player is might matter. I've *consistently* gotten HDR to work with VLC on a Ryzen mobile GPU with a vega chip.

Comment: Your laptop needs to support HDR as well. You need to find out what graphics is being used in your machines and whether they support it. https://superuser.com/questions/1337995/how-to-determine-which-parts-do-not-support-4k-60-hz-potentially-hdr-via-h is relevant and probably a duplicate here.  At the very least more information is needed on the actual laptops such as processors model and whether it has a dedicated graphics (no clue if Macbooks allow that) as an absolute minimum... just "intel" tells us nearly nothing.

Comment: In theory a modern macbook *should* but details matter.

Comment: This video https://youtu.be/cQ_PR0p3xBs?si=1veAdFLejqQhgbiI suggests that Apple is doing something slightly dumb in their display output, for a 1080p display they effectively scale up 2x and run at 4k (if I am interpreting it right) so by default 4k would end up trying to run at 8k. The video suggests that there is some scaling option that can be turned off to run at proper "native" resolution.

Comment: @Mokubai yes the M2 has XDR screen and can display HDR videos in the internal display without problem